Spring-kafka-test - unexpected dependency version
Using spring boot 3.1.11
spring-kafka - 3.0.16
Trying to update kafka-clients from 3.4.1 to 3.5.1
According to the docs, the three should work together.
However i noticed that spring-kafka-test still brings the old client (3.4.1) which causes issues.
Tried to exclude or force later version on spring-kafka-test but is has side effects and doesn't really work.
It should work according to the docs compatibility matrix, so why the older version?
[BTWs:

i don't want to update spring-kafka to 3.1.x because it requires updating spring-boot as well]

Manually adding testImplementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:3.5.1' won't work as it gets runtime exceptions (e.g java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/server/metrics/KafkaMetricsGroup)




My understanding is the matrix only refers to the clients, but the tests package needs the Kafka server, and upgrading the clients to a newer version isn't compatible with that. So, you'd also have to upgrade kafka_2.13, kafka-server-common, and maybe others

what do you mean by upgrading kafka_2.13? I don't ask for it directly, it is brought by spring-kafka-test. Beside, won't it be really weird if spring-kafka is compatible but spring-kafka-test isn't?

I mean also adding dependencies for that package to override what spring-kafka-test brings in. I don't think it's weird, since that package brings the whole kafka server dependency rather than just clients

See this one: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/appendix/override-boot-dependencies.html. So, technically with Spring Boot, there is just enough to have that property in your POM: <kafka.version>3.5.1</kafka.version>
